# Ruby inheritance and advised approach?

Tags: ruby

What I want is a single API which determines the class to delegate methods to based on a parameter passed through initializer. Here is a basic example:

```
module MyApp
  class Uploader
    def initialize(id)
      # stuck here
      # extend, etc. "include Uploader#{id}"
    end
  end
end

# elsewhere
module MyApp
  class UploaderGoogle
    def upload(file)
      # provider-specific uploader
    end
  end
end
```

My desired outcome:

```
MyApp::Uploader('Google').upload(file)
# calls MyApp::UploaderGoogle.upload method
```

Please be aware the above is for demonstration purposes only. I will actually be passing an object which contains an attribute with the uploader id. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but if you want to `include` a module:

```
module MyApp
  class Uploader
    def initialize(id)
      mod = ("Uploader"+id).constantize
      self.send(:include, mod)
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to extend your class with a module:

```
module MyApp
  class Uploader
    def initialize(id)
      mod = ("Uploader"+id).constantize
      self.class.send(:extend, mod)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a simple subclass. `UploaderGoogle < Uploader` Uploader defines the basic interface and then the subclasses define the provider specific methods, calling super as necessary to perform the upload. Untested code OTTOMH below…

```
module MyApp
    class Uploader
        def initialize(id)
            @id = id
        end

        def upload
            #perform upload operation based on configuration of self. Destination, filename, whatever
        end
    end

    class GoogleUploader < Uploader
        def initialize(id)
            super
            #google-specific stuff
        end

        def upload
            #final configuration/preparation
            super
        end
    end
end
```

Something along those lines. To base this on a passed parameter, I'd use a `case` statement.

```
klass = case paramObject.identifierString
    when 'Google'
        MyApp::GoogleUploader
    else
        MyApp::Uploader
    end
```

Two things: If you do this in several places, probably extract it into a method. Second, if you're getting the input from the user, you've got a lot of anti-injection work to do as well if you, for instance, create a class name directly from a provided string.